# ERROR: shrink of file system cache did not fully complete. Result: 21

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdata, ios7

its my first day using ios 7
i get this line in log hundreds of times per second.
i didn't get it before with the same code with iOS 6
maybe thats caused by :

```
    [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)];
```

it does not happen when i remove this line

do anybody know what's the meaning of this error ?

Comment: I am seeing this too today, it's weird, I don't know what it means either. No one talks about this from Google search.

Comment: Interesting error. Were you able to figure out the reason?

Comment: i cant remember exactly but i think the url was returning nothing..